# I am a bit lost as to the meaning of this C preprocessor statement,

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, undef

So, to start off, here's the code, with actual names switched for generic ones to limit confusion.

```
/* Get the list of Hotkey commands */
#define A_COMMANDS_MACRO(a, b, c, d) a = b ,
enum {
#include "commandsFile.def"
} ;
#undef  A_COMMANDS_MACRO
```

This is a snippet from some source code I have been looking over and considering forking as a way to familiarize myself with the intricacies of the **C** programming language. So, to my untrained eye, this appears to do nothing. To my brain, defining something and then immediately undefining it would seem to cancel each other out.

Obviously, I realize that I'm wrong. But why am I wrong?

Comment: The `#define` is applied to containts of `commandsFile.def` file. Post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see there is usually called X-MACRO. The technique consists in defining macros via `#define`, and then including a file that makes use of them with `#include`.

As a very simple example, you could have a header (say *myheader.h*) that declared 2 functions in the form of:

```
int foo(MYTYPE a, MYTYPE_PTR b);
void bar(MYTYPE a, MYTYPE_PTR b);
```

And then, in your code:

```
#define MYTYPE int
#define MYTYPE_PTR int*
#include "myheader.h"
#undef MYTYPE
#undef MYTYPE_PTR
```

The `#undef`s are sometimes in the included file as well.

For more information, take a look [at this Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#X-Macros).

Comment: This is awesome. Next question though: How is that enum referenced since it doesn't have a name? For that matter, what is the point in the enum? Why not just include the file straight out?

Comment: @KenB: it could be just a way to check that command names are unique and to "syntax check" the .def file.

Answer (score 5):

The "commandsFile.def" file probably uses the "A_COMMANDS_MACRO" macro somewhere internally.

Remember that "#include" essentially pastes the included file into the including one, so the #define is still in effect when "commandsFile.def" is processed.

Answer (score 4):

The `commandsFile.def` should contain many lines:

```
A_COMMANDS_MACRO(A_COMMAND, 10, na, na)
A_COMMANDS_MACRO(OTHER_COMMAND, 23, na, na)
```

So that the code would create an enum with available commands and their codes.

It could be useful when this .def file is used by a program written in other language, so that instead of implementing text parsing, it uses C preprocessor to do this.